# Mongodb Aggregate Nested Group with Recent Updated Document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have assigned person, status inside my collection simply like below.

```
[
 {"ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398", "SPEC_ID" : "58411771", "STATUS": 1, "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-21T04:10:23.000Z")},
 {"ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398", "SPEC_ID" : "58411772", "STATUS": 4, "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-22T04:10:23.000Z")},
 {"ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398", "SPEC_ID" : "58411774", "STATUS": 4, "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-23T04:10:23.000Z")},
 {"ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398", "SPEC_ID" : "58411774", "STATUS": 3, "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-24T04:10:23.000Z")},
 {"ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322311", "SPEC_ID" : "58411775", "STATUS": 1, "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-25T04:10:23.000Z")},
 {"ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322311", "SPEC_ID" : "58411779", "STATUS": 3, "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-23T04:10:23.000Z")},
 {"ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322322", "SPEC_ID" : "58411777", "STATUS": 1, "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-20T04:10:23.000Z")},
 {"ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322322", "SPEC_ID" : "58411778", "STATUS": 4, "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-21T04:10:23.000Z")}
]
```

i want to group this data by **ASSIGN_ID** and inside that by **STATUS** count of each **STATUS** and recent updated **SPEC_ID** by **UPDATE_DATE**. same as below. (Expected Result)

```
[  
   {  
      "ASSIGN_ID":"583f84bce58725f76b322398",
      "STATUS_GROUP":[  
         {  
            "STATUS":1,
            "COUNT":1
         },
         {  
            "STATUS":3,
            "COUNT":1
         },
         {  
            "STATUS":4,
            "COUNT":2
         }
      ],
      "SPEC_ID": "58411774"
   },
   {  
      "ASSIGN_ID":"583f84bce58725f76b322311",
      "STATUS_GROUP":[  
         {  
            "STATUS":1,
            "COUNT":1
         },
         {  
            "STATUS":3,
            "COUNT":1
         }
      ],
      "SPEC_ID": "58411775"
   },
   {  
      "ASSIGN_ID":"583f84bce58725f76b322322",
      "STATUS_GROUP":[  
         {  
            "STATUS":1,
            "COUNT":1
         },
         {  
            "STATUS":4,
            "COUNT":1
         }
      ],
      "SPEC_ID": "58411778"
   }
]
```

however, i was able to write the nested group by **STATUS** and **ASSIGN_ID**. unable to get the recent **SPEC_ID**. please find the query below.

```
            Modal.aggregate([
              {"$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "INSPECTED_BY": "$INSPECTED_BY",
                    "STATUS": "$STATUS"
                },
                "total": { "$sum": 1 }
              }},
              {"$group": {
                "_id": "$_id.INSPECTED_BY",
                "data": { "$push": {
                    "STATUS": "$_id.STATUS",
                    "total": "$total"
                }}
              }}]);
```

and it return a data set like below.

```
[  
   {  
      "ASSIGN_ID":"583f84bce58725f76b322398",
      "STATUS_GROUP":[  
         {  
            "STATUS":1,
            "COUNT":1
         },
         {  
            "STATUS":3,
            "COUNT":1
         },
         {  
            "STATUS":4,
            "COUNT":2
         }
      ],
   },
   {  
      "ASSIGN_ID":"583f84bce58725f76b322311",
      "STATUS_GROUP":[  
         {  
            "STATUS":1,
            "COUNT":1
         },
         {  
            "STATUS":3,
            "COUNT":1
         }
      ],

   },
   {  
      "ASSIGN_ID":"583f84bce58725f76b322322",
      "STATUS_GROUP":[  
         {  
            "STATUS":1,
            "COUNT":1
         },
         {  
            "STATUS":4,
            "COUNT":1
         }
      ],
   }
]
```

Comment: Your documents do not have the field `INSPECTED_BY`, is that a deliberate omission?

Comment: you can use $first in command,  db.testCollection.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: { ASSIGN_ID: "$ASSIGN_ID", STATUS: "$STATUS" }, count: { "$sum": 1 } ,"SPEC_ID":{$first:"$SPEC_ID"}} }, { $group: { _id: "$_id.ASSIGN_ID", STATUS_GROUP: { $push: { STATUS: "$_id.STATUS", count: "$count" } } ,"SPEC_ID":{$first:"$SPEC_ID"} }}])

Comment: radhakrishnan, it returns an error call MongoError: invalid operator '$first'

Answer (score 1):

You need to **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** the documents getting into the pipeline first then in your **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage return the latest `SPEC_ID` field for each group with the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator.

Running the following pipeline should give your the desired result:

```
Model.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "ASSIGN_ID": 1, "STATUS": 1, "UPDATE_DATE": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "ASSIGN_ID": "$ASSIGN_ID",                
                "STATUS" : "$STATUS",
            },
            "SPEC_ID": { "$first": "$SPEC_ID" },
            "COUNT": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.ASSIGN_ID",
            "STATUS_GROUP": { 
                "$push": {
                    "STATUS": "$_id.STATUS",
                    "COUNT": "$COUNT"
                }
            },
            "SPEC_ID": { "$first": "$SPEC_ID" }
        }
    }
]).exec(callback);
```